# C# кастомный ValidationAttribute не работает ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, aop

Здравствуйте! Сделал свой атрибут валидации, который наследуется от `ValidationAttribute`, переопределил метод `IsValid(object value,  ValidationContext validationContext)` и прописал атрибут свойству `Login` в классе `RegisterModel`. Все базовые атрибуты валидации прекрасно работают, однако этот - нет. 0 результата - в формах валидация не работает, только от встроенных атрибутов. Даже точки остановки не работают. Сам метод проверяет, существует ли пользователь с таким логином.

Код класса атрибута:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class UniqueLoginAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        Context Context = new Context(); // База данных (Entity Framework)
        public UniqueLoginAttribute(string Error)
        {
            ErrorMessage = Error;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            string temp = value.ToString().ToLower();
            if (Context.Users.Where(x => x.Login.ToLower() == temp).Count() == 0)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Код поля Login:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обов'язкове поле")]
        [DisplayName("Логін")]
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Логін повинен містити не менше 5 символів.")]
        [MaxLength(14, ErrorMessage = "Логін повинен містити не більше 14 символів.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Логін повинен містити тільки букви латинського алфавіту і цифри.")]
        [UniqueLogin("Користувач з заданим логіном вже зареєстрований!")]
        public string Login { get; set; }
```

Comment: Код следует прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev сейчас сделаю

Comment: @Vlad в данной реализации работу вашего атрибута можно проверить в дебаге только если модель прошла проверку на клиенте и отправилась на сервер. Вы уверены что на клиенте у вас нет ошибок ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что у вас нет ошибок сборки? Отсутствующие точки останова указывают на эту проблему. Я скомпилировал и выполнил ваш атрибут без каких-либо проблем - он был вызван и выполнен правильно.
Одна вещь, которую нужно помнить: метод в вашем контроллере все еще будет выполнен, даже если ваша проверка не удалась, там нужно проверить `ModelState.IsValid`.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeModel um)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.updateError = "Update Failure";
    }
    else
    {
        //....
    }
    return View(um);
}
```